# 2006 Chevy Silverado missing dash lights

Tags: chevrolet, silverado

I have a 2006 Chevy Silverado with several missing lights on buttons. See pictures below. I have seen in a couple places that they are soldered on and you can't replace them. Is this true? If not, how do you fix them?

[image: Dash]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You are welcome to add the pictures here directly.  As of right now, I can't see them due to where they're hosted.

Comment: I thought about that after I posted. I'll have to do that tonight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to replace the module or switch that has the lights out. On the older body style chevys you were able to replace just the bulbs but not anymore.

Comment: So basically... don't bother unless you REALLY want to get it fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can replace the bulbs, but it's not the easiest thing to do. You need to have **patience** and **a soldering iron**. Many people take this time to replace the bulbs with LED bulbs, in a color of their choice. It's also recommended that you replace all of the bulbs at the same time to alleviate having to tear it all apart again in the near future for the same purpose or so you don't have some bulbs brighter than others. Here are some examples which should prove good for you.

[Dash cluster bulb replacement - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fC_dE0iZtxE).

[Write up for the above replacement](http://usedcarsit.com/gauge-light-bulb-replacement-chevy-buick-pontiac-cadillac).

[Pulling steering wheel controls to get to the bulbs - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RP-KV0m6Tj0).

[Bulb replacement on 2002-2009 Chevrolet radio - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=moPkwIXpQS4).

Comment: That sounds like work. ;-) Not sure I want to go to that much work. I'll live with it for now.